# How to delay html/css load until item is in viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css, load, viewport

I have an animation on a chart but I want the CSS animation to load once it becomes into the users viewport. Currently it loads on the page load but this means that once the user has scrolled to the section the animation has already occurred.

The HTML & CSS can be seen below:

```css
.chart[data-percent='100'] .outer {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  -webkit-animation: show100 2s;
  animation: show100 2s;
}

.chart[data-percent='96'] .outer {
  stroke-dashoffset: 22;
  -webkit-animation: show96 2s;
  animation: show96 2s;
}

.chart[data-percent='77'] .outer {
  stroke-dashoffset: 123;
  -webkit-animation: show75 2s;
  animation: show75 2s;
}

.chart[data-percent='75'] .outer {
  stroke-dashoffset: 133;
  -webkit-animation: show75 2s;
  animation: show75 2s;
}

.chart[data-percent='52'] .outer {
  stroke-dashoffset: 257;
  -webkit-animation: show52 2s;
  animation: show52 2s;
}

.chart[data-percent='50'] .outer {
  stroke-dashoffset: 267;
  -webkit-animation: show50 2s;
  animation: show50 2s;
}

.chart[data-percent='25'] .outer {
  stroke-dashoffset: 401;
  -webkit-animation: show25 2s;
  animation: show25 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes show100 {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 537;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes show96 {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 537;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 22;
  }
}

@keyframes show75 {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 537;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 124;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes show52 {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 537;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 257;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes show50 {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 537;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 267;
  }
}

@keyframes show25 {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 537;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 401;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row stat-wheel">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <p class="stat-figure">52%</p>
    <figure class="chart" data-percent="52">
      <svg width="200" height="200">
        <circle class="outer" cx="95" cy="95" r="85" transform="rotate(-90, 95, 95)"/>
      </svg>
    </figure>
    <p class="white center">increase in sales generated through campaigns</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <p class="stat-figure">77%</p>
    <figure class="chart" data-percent="77">
      <svg width="200" height="200">
        <circle class="outer" cx="95" cy="95" r="85" transform="rotate(-90, 95, 95)"/>
      </svg>
    </figure>
    <p class="white center">return on investment in the first 2 months</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <p class="stat-figure">96%</p>
    <figure class="chart" data-percent="96">
      <svg width="200" height="200">
        <circle class="outer" cx="95" cy="95" r="85" transform="rotate(-90, 95, 95)"/>
      </svg>
    </figure>
    <p class="white center">increase in the quality of sales leads generated</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In short: 1) an animation should be activated by toggling a class when the element enters in the viewport; 2) you know the element is in the viewport using [intersection observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) e.g.: https://codepen.io/fcalderan/pen/PLLOpW

Comment: I made you a snippet and fixed your invalid `</P>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can checkout the [intersection observer api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API), it tells you when an element becomes visible in your viewport. You can listen to it and then start your animation.

Answer (score 0):

A very clean way would be using vanilla JS.
[Link with explanation](https://gomakethings.com/how-to-test-if-an-element-is-in-the-viewport-with-vanilla-javascript/)

```
// (c) 2017 Chris Ferdinandi
var isInViewport = function (elem) {
    var distance = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
        distance.top >= 0 &&
        distance.left >= 0 &&
        distance.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
        distance.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );
};

var findMe = document.querySelector('.row stat-wheel');

window.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
    if (isInViewport(findMe)) {
        console.log('In viewport!');
    } else {
    console.log('Nope...');
  }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript library to animate elements as they scroll into view.

https://scrollrevealjs.org/